# What is the meaning of package name before @git in package-lock.json

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I try to run `npm install`, I got an error:

```
Could not install from "node_modules/eth-sig-util/ethereumjs-abi@git+https:/github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

So I went to check the diff for `package-lock.json`, and noticed npm somehow modified

```
"ethereumjs-abi": "git+https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git",
```

into

```
"ethereumjs-abi": "ethereumjs-abi@git+https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git",
```

which breaks the `npm install`, so I'm wondering what is the meaning of placing package name before `@git` and why it breaks the install process.
It works after I delete the `ethereumjs-abi@` prefix, but it shows up after I run `npm install` and breaks again...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A @git use to install the package from the git repo.

like: you fork package git repo into your Git account and you change some part of the package now you want to that install that changed package in project you can use @git+'git repo URL of your changed repo'.

here `ethereumjs-abi` package install from the `https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git"` git repo:

```
"ethereumjs-abi": "git+https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git",
```

Comment: Thanks! but do you know why npm adds ethereumjs-abi before @git?

Comment: I don't know about it.

Comment: thanks for the solution